# Handling Errors in Health Checks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have some code like this that goes in my Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<StartupProbe>("Startup Probe")
    .AddCheck<LivenessProbe>("Liveness Probe")
    .AddCheck<ReadinessProbe>("Readiness Probe");
```

It adds three `IHealthCheck` classes to the [check the health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-6.0) of my service while running in Kubernetes.

Most of the time, it works just fine.  But sometimes it fails with `TaskCanceledException` stating that "A task was canceled".

These health checks occur every 5 seconds or so, so a cancelled one every now and then is not really a big deal.  But I need to suppress the message.  They add up till my log files are full of them.

I read about using [Exception Handling Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0), but the docs are confusing me in the following ways:

1. It talks about loading "pages".  I am working with a service.  It does not have any UI (except for Swagger UI).
2. The Exception Handling Middleware docs seem to want me to decorate a controller with [atrributes] to make it work.  But the `AddHealthChecks` method does not have a controller.  It sets up the routes for me.
3. I only want to handle the `TaskCanceledException` and (preferably) only for the health check calls.  But I have not been able to see a way to limit how it handles exceptions.

I also saw the option of using an Exception Filter.  But the docs for that say to use Exception Handling Middleware instead of that.

**Is there a way to handle errors for my health checks?**  (And only my health checks)

NOTE: Here is the full exception I get, just in case it is useful:

```
"EventId": 1,
"LogLevel": "Error",
"Category": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware",
"Message": "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.",
"Exception": "
    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.DefaultHealthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync(Func\u00602 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.HealthCheckMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    at Dynatrace.OneAgent.Introspection.Shared.OwinMiddlewareBase\u00601.Invoke(Context context)
    at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HeaderPropagation.HeaderPropagationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    at Dynatrace.OneAgent.Introspection.Shared.OwinMiddlewareBase\u00601.Invoke(Context context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)",
"State": {
    "Message": "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.",
    "{OriginalFormat}": "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request."
}
```

Comment: A bit of a hacky way, but have you tried wrapping contents of `CheckHealthAsync` with `try { /* ... your health check code */ } catch(TaskCanceledException) { }`?

Comment: @KifoPL - I already have that in there.  This error is not occurring in my code.  It is just in the generic code of the Microsoft Heath Check code (from what I can see).

Comment: I found [this question](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28568#issuecomment-784013537) in github and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474213/asp-net-core-healthchecks-randomly-fails-with-taskcanceledexception-or-operation) in SO, will they help?

Comment: @TinyWang - I had read through those as well.  It was in trying to implement them that lead me to this question.  One way needs a route and a controller (not shown in either of the questions you linked to), and the other way is not recommended by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working.  I was able to reproduce this error using a console application (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73791547/get-httpclient-to-abort-the-connection) for details).

I added a middleware to address the issue.  I added the following class:

```
/// <summary>
/// This middleware will catch any cancellation exceptions (OperationCanceledException or TaskCanceledException) in health checks, and return 204 No Content.
/// Adapted from: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28568#issuecomment-784013537
/// Relevant Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73791547/get-httpclient-to-abort-the-connection
/// </summary>
public class HealthCheckCancellationSuppressionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public HealthCheckCancellationSuppressionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            // Forward to next middleware
            await next(httpContext);
        }
        //Note TaskCanceledException inherits from OperationCanceledException (so this works for both)
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            if (httpContext != null && httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/health"))
            {
                // If we have a response already, then just let that happen.
                if (httpContext.Response.HasStarted) return;

                // Set a status code. Response will likely not be seen by client as we expect all cancellations to come from httpContext.RequestAborted
                // Why 204 No Content? I could not find any other appropriate status code.
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status204NoContent;
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I then added the above middleware BEFORE the call to `AddHealthChecks`, like this:

```
app.UseMiddleware<HealthCheckCancellationSuppressionMiddleware>();
```

This got rid of the logs of `TaskCanceledException`s.