# Graph API - Authentication Token and Task Cancellation Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, windows-services, email-processing

We have an application "App1" in Azure will all the required permissions and have 7 instances of a Windows service in C# that uses the same Azure Application "App1" to connect to Outlook Mailboxes. The code is same across all the 7 windows service instances with the difference in config i.e. each instance connecting to a unique Mailbox.

Question:

We do authentication using the code below and each service is running on its own Server(Windows), when this authentication code is executed for lets say all the services will there be issue with the token overlapping since it uses the same Azure "App1" or since its connecting to a unique Mailbox for each service instance it wont be a problem and have unique access token per service instance.

```
AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = null;
        IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage inboxMessage = null;
        try
        {

            string tenantId = "TenantId";
            string clientId = "ClientId";
            string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
            var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                .Build();
            var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //return;
        }

        if (authResult != null)
        {
            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(requestMessage =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }));
```

We get below error frequently and want to know if this setup could be affecting our applications. If not what is the reason we are getting such errors.

```
    Message: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.MessageAttachmentsCollectionRequest.<GetAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at GraphPOC.EmailMain.<GetDataAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
Category: Error
Priority: -1
EventId: 0
Severity: Error
Title:
App Domain: GraphPOC.exe
ProcessId: 988
Process Name: D:\Program Files\GraphPOC.exe
Thread Name: 
Win32 ThreadId:4884
Extended Properties: 
    Callstack=   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceEventCache.get_Callstack()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.WriteFooter(TraceEventCache eventCache)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedTextWriterTraceListener.TraceData(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, Object data)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener.TraceData(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, Object data)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource.TraceData(TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id, LogEntry logEntry, TraceListenerFilter traceListenerFilter)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.ProcessLog(LogEntry log)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.Write(LogEntry log)
   at GraphPOC.EmailMain.<GetDataAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Graph.MessageAttachmentsCollectionRequest.<GetAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(Action action, Boolean allowInlining, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord, Object cancellationException)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken tokenToRecord)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1.TrySetCanceled(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SetTaskCanceled(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource, TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<>c__DisplayClass59_0.<StartContentBuffering>b__0(Task contentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(Task task, Boolean needsProtection)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1.TrySetException(Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<LoadIntoBufferAsync>b__0(Task copyTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.TryRunInline(Task task, Boolean taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation.InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(Task task, Boolean needsProtection)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1.TrySetException(Exception exception)
   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamAsyncResult.Complete(Object result)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult baseStreamResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ChunkParser.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when we use client credential flow to generate access token and use it to call the graph api, let's assume your "App1" had plenty of application api perissions like `User.ReadWrite.All,Mail.ReadBasic.All,Files.ReadWrite.All`, then the token will contain all these api permissions so that it can be used to search for users/mails/files. As you can see, this token will contain such a big permission.

Then go back to your scenario, you don't need to worry about the `token overlapping` because token just represent the `authorization`, since it contained correct api permission, then the token generated by each of your application can be used in other application because they all had the same configuration. In other words they are all valid.

About your exception, I'm not sure which line reported it, you may try to debug you code to find the problematic code. and I'm afraid it may relate to `return Task.FromResult(0);`. I searched for the error message and here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474213/asp-net-core-healthchecks-randomly-fails-with-taskcanceledexception-or-operation) met the same error. Anyway it seems to be an unexpected task issue.

Since you are now using the graph client, I'm afraid you can call graph api directly without obtaining the access token first. Like code below:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
string tenantId = "TenantId";
string clientId = "ClientId";
string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```